# How can I replace a substring of a string with another in Haskell without using external Libraries like MissingH?

Tags: string, haskell, substring

I would like to replace a substring with a string in Haskell, without using external libraries, and, if it is possible, with good performance.

I thought about using the [**`Data.Text`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.1.3/docs/Data-Text.html) replace functions, but I don't want to port my entire program to use the `Text` type instead of `Strings`. Would packing the `String` into a `Text` value, then replacing what I wanted to, then unpacking that Text value to a `String` be slow on a lot of `Strings`?

Comment: For many interpretations of "good performance" you *will* need to replace `String` with `Text`.

Comment: Porting your entire program to use `Text` instead of `String` is unlikely to be difficult, just tedious. There are corner cases concerning APIs using `String`s without the option to use `Text`/`ByteString`, but for the most part it's just a matter of changing the type in one place and then correcting the type errors that crop up elsewhere.

Comment: if you want to replace a `Data.Text`, use [`replace`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts/text/Data-Text.html#v:replace)

Comment: Why doesn't ByteString have a replace function like the one in Text?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this (untested):

```
replace :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
replace needle replacement haystack
  = case begins haystack needle of
      Just remains -> replacement ++ remains
      Nothing      -> case haystack of
                        []     -> []
                        x : xs -> x : replace needle replacement xs

begins :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
begins haystack []                = Just haystack
begins (x : xs) (y : ys) | x == y = begins xs ys
begins _        _                 = Nothing
```

But in general you will get performance gains from switching your program to use `Text`s instead of `String`s.

Comment: ok, im gonna port my program to the text type, but how would i read a file as text instead of a string? there is no function for that, like when using bytestrings. do i just convert the string to a text type?

Comment: @nils8950 There are no functions for that?  [Are you sure](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=FilePath+-%3E+IO+Text)?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson thanks!! i didnt find that for some reason.

Comment: @nils8950 Probably because you didn't use `hoogle` or `grep`!  Eyeballs have been inferior tools since at least the 80s ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Here is my solution

```
import Data.List (intercalate)
import Data.List.Split (splitOn)

replace from to = intercalate to . splitOn from
```

Example

```
replace "squirrel" "platypus" "Daddy, I want a squirrel !"
```

Daddy, I want a platypus !