# How to replace a string with another in haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to replace a string from an input file with a different string. I was searching for a method but it seems i can only alter the string character by character.  For example in the my code below

```
replace :: String -> String 
replace [] = [] 
replace (x:xs) = if x == '@' then 'y':replace xs --y is just a random char
                             else x:replace xs

searching :: String -> IO String
searching filename = do
    text <- readFile filename
    return(replace text)


main :: IO ()
main = do

  n <- searching "test.sf"
  writeFile "writefile.html" n
```

I want to find the first occurrence of the string "@title", but i cant seem to find a method to do so as mentioned before, i can only access the char '@'. Is there a method for doing such a task.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I replace a substring of a string with another in Haskell without using external Libraries like MissingH?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880299/how-can-i-replace-a-substring-of-a-string-with-another-in-haskell-without-using)

Comment: I think, that was already discussed here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880299/how-can-i-replace-a-substring-of-a-string-with-another-in-haskell-without-using

Comment: This is not really a duplicate. The other question specifically excludes using other libraries, which is a reasonable answer to this question.

Comment: For a general solution to this problem: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec

Comment: if you want to replace a `Data.Text`, use [`replace`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts/text/Data-Text.html#v:replace)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [Data.List.Utils](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MissingH/0.18.6/doc/html/Data-List-Utils.html#v%3areplace) replace, it's lazy and you can process a big file with some like:

```
main = getContents >>= putStr . replace "sourceString" "destinationString"
```

That's all!

A possible replace function could be

```
rep a b s@(x:xs) = if isPrefixOf a s

                     -- then, write 'b' and replace jumping 'a' substring
                     then b++rep a b (drop (length a) s)

                     -- then, write 'x' char and try to replace tail string
                     else x:rep a b xs

rep _ _ [] = []
```

another smart way (from Data.String.Utils)

```
replace :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
replace old new l = join new . split old $ l
```

Comment: Alternatively, using [Data.List.Split](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/split/0.2.1.1/doc/html/Data-List-Split.html) from the `split` package which is part of Haskell Platform, define `replace old new = intercalate new . splitOn old`.

Comment: A better option would be to use `replace :: Text -> Text -> Text -> Text ` from the `text` package: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.0/docs/Data-Text.html#v:replace