# How do you apply multiple cases in a replace in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, replace

I wrote a function to be able to clean word numbers for processing in Haskell. It needs to be able to change `-` into spaces (i.e. forty-five becomes forty five) and delete every other non-letter. I can define it recursively, but I'd really like to do something cleaner.

```
clean :: String -> String
clean "" = ""
clean ('-':cs) = ' ' : clean cs
clean (c:cs)
    | isLetter c  = c : clean cs
    | otherwise   = clean cs
```

This led me to defining a custom filter and defining a replace from [Data.List.Split](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MissingH-1.4.0.1/docs/Data-List-Utils.html) based on a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14908602/5299034), since I'm already using Data.List.Split.

```
clean :: String -> String
clean = filter (\c -> isLetter c || c == ' ') . replace "-" " " . filter (/= ' ')
  where
    replace :: String -> String -> String -> String
    replace old new = intercalate new . splitOn old
```

This version is even messier as a whole. Also, this version doesn't remove spaces in the original string. Is a different convention or something built-in that would allow me to do this with use a clean one-liner?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the most powerful functions for dealing with lists is [`concatMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap) (a.k.a. `>>=`). You can write your `clean` function like so:

```
clean :: String -> String
clean = concatMap (\c -> if c == '-' then " " else [c | isLetter c])
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two things here:

1. you need to remove everything that is not a letter or hyphen; and
2. next we replace hyphens with spaces.

So we can do this with a pipeline with `filter` and `replace`:

```
  import Data.Bool(bool)
  import Data.Char(isLetter)

   map (\x -> bool ' ' x (x /= '-')) . filter (\x -> isLetter x || x == '-')
-- \____________ __________________/   \______________ ____________________/
--              v                                     v
--             (2)                                   (1)
```

We can use list comprehension to do the mapping and filtering like:

```
import Data.Bool(bool)
import Data.Char(isLetter)

clean l = [bool ' ' x (x /= '-') | x <- l, isLetter x || x == '-']
```

We can also use a single function, and perform for instance a `concatMap`:

```
import Data.Bool(bool)
import Data.Char(isLetter)

concatMap (\x -> bool (bool "" " " (x == '-')) [x] (isLetter x))
```

So here we concatenate the mapping of `x` to `""` in case `x` is not a letter and the hyphen, or the empty string in case it is not a letter nor the hyphen, or `[x]` (so a 1-char string) in case `x` is a a letter.

Comment: Thanks for this! I've not run across `bool` before. It looks like it's basically an if-else?

Comment: @BrainFRZ: it is a *catamorphism* of `Bool`, but for a boolean, this indeed acts like an `if-then-else`, with `bool <res-if-false> <res-if-true> <condition>`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very good use case for `do` notation in the list monad.

```
clean :: String -> String
clean string = do
  character <- string         -- For each character in the string...
  case character of
    '-'            -> " "     -- If it’s a dash, replace with a space.
    c | isLetter c -> pure c  -- If it’s a letter, return it.
    _              -> []      -- Otherwise, discard it.
```

This is ultimately simple syntactic sugar for `concatMap`. `pure c` can also be written `[c]` if you prefer; and less importantly, `" "` can be written `pure ' '` or `[' ']`. And as an alternative, you may find this more readable with the `MultiWayIf` extension:

```
if
  | character == '-'   -> " "
  | isLetter character -> pure character
  | otherwise          -> []
```

Finally, note that `isLetter` returns true for all Unicode letters. If you only care about ASCII, you may want to use `isAscii c && isLetter c`, or `isAsciiUpper c || isAsciiLower c`.