# Haskell replace characters in string

Tags: haskell

Supposing I had the string "HELLO WORLD" is there a way I can call a function that replaces the character 'O' in the string with the character 'X' so that the new string would look like "HELLX WXRLD"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I replace a substring of a string with another in Haskell without using external Libraries like MissingH?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880299/how-can-i-replace-a-substring-of-a-string-with-another-in-haskell-without-using)

Comment: Did you search at all as this question has come up numerous times.

Comment: if you want to replace a `Data.Text`, use [`replace`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts/text/Data-Text.html#v:replace)

Answer (score 40):

How about:

```
let 
    repl 'o' = 'x'
    repl  c   = c
in  map repl "Hello World"
```

If you need to replace additional characters later, just add clauses to the `repl` function.

Comment: Oh, I see. My solution is indeed a bit complicated.

Comment: Pattern matching is king.

Comment: Can you do this with a lambda in one line? If so, another +1 from me :)

Comment: @vikingsteve In a long line, why not? `map (\case ....) "Hello World"` (just fill in the ... :)

Answer (score 17):

**Alternative 1 - Using MissingH**

First:

```
import Data.List.Utils (replace)
```

Then use:

```
replace "O" "X" "HELLO WORLD"
```

**Alternative 2 - Using Control.Monad**

One funny bastard:

```
import Control.Monad (mfilter)

replace a b = map $ maybe b id . mfilter (/= a) . Just
```

Example:

```
λ> replace 'O' 'X' "HELLO WORLD"
"HELLX WXRLD"
```

**Alternative 3 - Using if**

Amon's suggestions was probably the finest I believe! No imports and easy to read and understand!

But to be picky - there's no need for semicolon:

```
replace :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
replace a b = map $ \c -> if c == a then b else c
```

Answer (score 15):

Sorry for picking up this old thread but why not use lambda expressions?

```
λ> let replaceO = map (\c -> if c=='O' then 'X'; else c)
λ> replaceO "HELLO WORLD"
"HELLX WXRLD"`
```

Answer (score 5):

If you depend on the `text` package (like 99.99% of Haskell applications), you can use [`T.replace`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.4.1/docs/Data-Text.html#v:replace):

```
>>> replace "ofo" "bar" "ofofo"
"barfo"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possible solution using divide and conquer:

```
replaceO [] = []
replaceO (x:xs) = 
     if x == 'O' 
     then 'X' : replaceO xs 
     else x : replaceO xs
```

First, you set the edge condition `"replaceO [] = []"`. 
If the list is empty, there is nothing to replace, returning an empty list.

Next, we take the string and divide it into head and tail. in this case `'H':"ELLOWORLD"` 
If the head is equal to 'O', it will replace it with 'X'. and apply the replaceO function to the rest of the string.
If the head is not equal to 'O', then it will put the head back where it is and apply the replaceO function to the rest of the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
replace :: Char -> Char -> String -> String
replace _ _ [] = []
replace a b (x : xs) 
                  | x == a = [b] ++ replace a b xs
                  | otherwise = [x] ++ replace a b xs
```

I'm new to Haskell and I've tried to make it simpler for others like me.

Answer (score -2):

I guess this could be useful.

```
main = print $ charRemap "Hello WOrld" ['O','o'] ['X','x']

charRemap :: [Char] -> [Char] -> [Char] -> [Char]
charRemap [] _ _ = []
charRemap (w:word) mapFrom mapTo =
    if snd state
        then mapTo !! fst state : charRemap word mapFrom mapTo
        else w : charRemap word mapFrom mapTo
    where
        state = hasChar w mapFrom 0

hasChar :: Char -> [Char] -> Int -> (Int,Bool)
hasChar _ [] _ = (0,False)
hasChar c (x:xs) i | c == x = (i,True)
                   | otherwise = hasChar c xs (i+1)
```