# Haskell Replace characters in string with string

Tags: string, haskell, replace, char

This is an extension of this question: [Haskell replace characters in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545253/)

I would like to tweak the following expression to replace a char with a string

```
let replaceO = map (\c -> if c=='O' then 'X'; else c)
```

In the end, I would the following results (XX can be a string of any length):

```
replaceO "HELLO WORLD"
"HELLXX WXXRLD"
```

Comment: You won't be able to do this with just `map`, take a look at `concat` and consider `(\c -> if c == 'O' then "X" else [c])`.  Notice that each character gets turned into a string instead.

Comment: That looks promising, but will it work for something like this: map (\x -> if x `elem` guesses then x else '-') word

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  Your comment here needs more context to make enough sense.  If you're trying to replace certain characters with another character then you want `map`.  If you are trying to replace certain characters with a new string, then use `concatMap`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `concatMap`:

```
let replace0 = concatMap (\c -> if c=='O' then "X" else "XX")
```

Comment: The introduction to [Monads are Trees with Grafting](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2010/01/monads-are-trees-with-grafting.html?m=1) gives a good overview of the general concept of replacing elements with bigger pieces.

Answer (score 0):

You kind formulate your problem in terms of traversing and accumulating based on a condition, something like this,

```
replace :: String -> Char -> String -> String
replace xs c s = foldr go [] xs

 where go x acc = if x == c  then acc ++ s
                             else acc ++ [x]
```

For you example:

```
>replace "HELLO WORLD" 'O' "XXX" 
> "HELLXXX WXXXRLD"
```

Comment: AFAICS, this has quadratic complexity. Appending "on the right" is inefficient. I'd switch to `foldr`, or use `concatMap` (as @Lee suggests) instead.