# Indent all lines in a string

Tags: string, haskell

I have some types with custom `Show` instances defined. They are structured like this:

```
data TopLevel = TopLevel SndLevel
data SndLevel = SndLevel Int

instance Show SndLevel where
  show (SndLevel i) = "SndLevel: \n\t" ++ (show i)
```

My `Show` instance for `SndLevel` produces nice looking strings that look like the following when they appear in my output:

```
SndLevel: 
  5
```

I would like to create a `Show` instance for `topLevel` that causes `TopLevel (SndLevel 5)` to look like this when printed to the terminal:

```
TopLevel
  SndLevel
    5
```

I was hoping to find a function built into Haskell that would add `"\t"` at the front of a string and before each location where `"\n"` appears in that string.

The best solution I found would go along the lines of the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545253/haskell-replace-characters-in-string) post. In this case, I would replace `"\n"` with `"\t\n"`.

I assume I'm not the first person to need Show instances for hierarchically organized data in Haskell, so I would like to know if there is a more idiomatic way to get this done. Is there some better solution to my problem?

p.s: I realize this kind of printing is not the best for the example datatypes I use above. The real datatypes I want to write instances for are product types, and so they don't read well when stretched out on one line. With that in mind, if there is a popular way to deal with this kind of problem without newlines and tabs, that could also solve my problem.

Comment: Yes, there are good libraries for pretty-printing. ...but the question is still off-topic by SO rules, because the answer shifts over time.

Comment: I'd move your pretty printing function outside from `Show`. The `Show` typeclass should not indent anything, since indentation copes with showing values of type `(A,B)`, `[A]`, and virtually any other container type. Further, the widespread convention is that `Show` should output its data using Haskell's syntax (breaking this in a library would be pretty bad -- in a program less so, though).

Comment: Thanks @chi, this clears things up.

Comment: I would consider just going for YAML serialization.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can solve this by using [**`lines :: String -> [String]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lines) and [**`unlines :: [String] -> String`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:unlines) to move from a `String` to a list of `String`s and back.

In between, we can make use of [**`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lines) to prepend all lines (a `String` is a list of `Char`s) with a tab, like:

```
indent :: String -> String
indent = unlines . map ('\t' :) . lines
```

For example:

```
Prelude> indent (show (SndLevel 5))
"\tSndLevel: \n\t\t5\n"
```

We can use this in our defintion of `Show` for both `SndLevel` and `TopLevel` like:

```
instance Show SndLevel where
    show (SndLevel n) = "SndLevel:" ++ '\n' : indent (show n)

instance Show TopLevel where
    show (TopLevel n) = "TopLevel:" ++ '\n' : indent (show n)
```

This thus gives us:

```
Prelude> print (TopLevel (SndLevel 5))
TopLevel:
    SndLevel:
        5
```

That being said, a `Show` is usually used to show a representation of the object that can usually be "injected" back inh the compiler/interpreter. The idea of using indentation is not bad at all, but perhaps it makes sence to define your own typeclass for that. You could make that typeclass more efficient by using a parameter that is passed and updated, that keeps track of the indentation level.

There are furthermore several ["*pretty printing*" libraries [Reddit]](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/8ilw75/there_are_too_many_prettyprinting_libraries/) that can print the structure of an object nicely. So instead of "*reinventing the wheel*", it might be worth using one of the packages listed on the Reddit page.

Comment: Nice answer.   State is unnecessary for indentation -- a simple function parameter (aka Reader) suffices.