# Where is the mistake in this replacing function in Haskell?

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming

I want to write a function which takes a string and replaces any number in the string with 7. For example "foo123" will be replaced to "foo777"

This is my function.

```
replace [] = []
replace (x:xs) =
    if x == ['0'..'9']
    then '7' : replace xs
    else x : replace xs
```

Comment: what do you have with that ?

Comment: That shouldn't even compile, you're trying to compare x to a list so Haskell will assume that you want to match on a list. [Possibible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880299/how-can-i-replace-a-substring-of-a-string-with-another-in-haskell-without-using)

Answer (score 6):

`==` does not test if `x` is an element of the list; it checks if `x` is *equal* to the list. Use the `elem` function instead.

```
replace [] = []
replace (x:xs) =
    if x `elem` ['0'..'9']
    then '7' : replace xs
    else x : replace xs
```

`if` is a pure expression that can be used anywhere another expression can be used, so you don't need to repeat the recursive call to `xs`:

```
replace [] = []
replace (x:xs) = (if x `elem` ['0'..'9'] then '7' else x) : replace xs
```

Finally, you can just use `map` instead of using explicit recursion.

```
replace xs = map (\x -> if x `elem` ['0'..'9'] then '7' else x) xs
```

or just

```
replace = map (\x -> if x `elem` ['0'..'9'] then '7' else x)
```

---

You may want to use `Data.Char.isDigit` instead:

```
import Data.Char
replace = map (\x -> if isDigit x then '7' else x)
```

Answer (score 2):

`==`  only tests if x is equal to the list, which it is not. You have to use the function `elem` which takes as its parameter one element and a list of element, and returns `true` if the element is in the list. So your code will be:

```
replace [] = []
replace (x:xs) =
    if elem x ['0'..'9']
    then '7' : replace xs
    else x : replace xs
```